# Using css div tables -widely supported yet?

Tags: html, css

I'm using a table element in my page layout (because I can't get divs to work 100% the way I want).

I just read this article about using a table style for divs:

http://www.digital-web.com/articles/everything_you_know_about_CSS_Is_wrong/

is this widely supported right now, is anyone using this method? If I look at major sites like twitter etc, I see tables being used, so I'm wondering if it's not a good idea to switch over,

Thanks

Comment: @BalusC: The question isn't related to the HTML `table` element, but rather the CSS `display: table` property.

Answer (score 2):

Seems to be supported in [all but Internet Explorer 5, 6 and 7.](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/display.html)